# Filtering Data from Excel with Python

Tags: python, excel, filter

I would like some guidance in a way to filter data from an excel sheet (.xlsx)

I will be exporting an extensive table from a website with 400x20. In this sheet, I need to apply 3 or 4 filters and collect the amount of info it shows then. For example:

1. Export .xlsx from website
2. Run python to filter

   - Filter by client A
   - Filter by task A
   - Filter by Person A
3. Repeat filter for different clients, tasks and persons
4. Collect the amount each person does inside each client.

I have been trying to complete this task with Pandas in python but I do not know if that was a good choice. Are there different modules/libraries for this ror is Panda a Good choice?

[This is basically what I have so far, before this I wrote raw_input() to describe which client and etc](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YLzQX.png)

Comment: Use xlrd for reading the excel. Then list comprehensions to filter the data.

Comment: If you want to include the code you're using, linking to a screenshot is not the best way, because people can't copy and paste a screenshot to test your implementation. I left the link there for now, but you should consider removing it when you add the code to the post.

Comment: Sorry about the ss, first time coming here - point taken.

Thank you for the advice!